# How can Dynamic Add and Remove View In android ? And this is also Store even if I closed the Application

Tags: android, android-view, android-linearlayout

In my Application I want to Add and Remove View (like `Button`, or `Textview`, `Checkbox` ) by Coding (Programming ).

In Details:

I have One `EditText` and One Add `Button`. User Enter Anything in `EditText` and Press the Add `Button` then this one is added in bellow `LinearLayout`, and whether User click on his/her added `Button` it will going to next `LinearLayout`.

I get sucess upto this.

but when user click the button in second `LinearLayout` then it will come back on first `Linearlayout`. I am getting error Here, i don't know where I made a Mistake.

And I also facing Problem about how can I Store this all. Like User Add 5 Button and closed the application and whenever he/she came back to application I need whatever he/she previously added.

Here is what i done.
 http://dynamicandroidview.blogspot.com/2011/12/how-to-add-view-in-android-by-coding.html

Comment: u can store the no. of added buttons in shared preferences and retrieve it whenever user uses app later

Comment: thanks for your replay, in shared preferences how can I store button object ? or I can just store the name of added button ? and how can I identify in which Linearlayout how many button is added by user ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a database table with minimum 2 columns in your case it will be id and buttonText.
Now when user clicks on the add button it will save text to the database and will create the button dynamically below any buttons which are already created before or as a new button.
Now in your onCreate method get the count of text thats stored in database.Some thing like the following code:

```
DB getData = DB.getInstance();
getData.open(this);
ArrayList<TextHolder> getList = new ArrayList<TextHolder>();
getList = getData.getAllTextFromGeT();
getData.close();
x = genList.size();
```

Here x will be the number/count of elements that are already stored in the database.Now you can another int say i and using this i and x in the for loop you can create buttons dynamically.
Inside the loop you can do something like the following to get text for all the buttons that are being created:

```
TextHolder firstOne = getList.get(i);
String text = firstOne.getText();
```

You will also need class with getters and setters method in order to convert DB elements into objects.Like in the above code getText() is our getter method which is getting elements from database and returning it here.
here text will be the text of the button.
So every-time users starts the application he will see all the buttons that he created when he ran the application before and newly added button will appear on the spot and also will be stored in the database for future retrieval.
Remember we are just storing text of the button and assigning it unique id which helps us to create the buttons.Hope this helps